# New Windows 2012 R2 Server on SoftLayer - AD DS no _msdcs resource entries created

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory

First - Many thanks to any for their support. I feel I am going slightly crazy. I have created a Virtual Machine on SoftLayer. It is Windows 2012 R2 SE. A vanilla/new install.

I want this machine to be an Active Directory server so once it is built I have logged in and change it to revert to itself only as the DNS Preferred Host and then from Server Manager carried out the Roles & Features installation of AD DS and DNS roles. New forest is ejk.com and new machine name is ad-test.ejk.com. Firewall is off.

The pre-requisites passes and the installation finishes and after the reboot I log in to find:

- nslookup says:
  DNS request timed out.
  Default server: UnKnown
  Address:    ::1
- Opening the DNS menu I find no entries at all for the expected domain (DS) or catalog (GC) under the DNS resource records
- It has created two Forward Lookup Zones

i) _msdcs.ejk.com entirely empty
ii) ejk.com
One entry => _msdcs
iii) No reverse lookup zones at all

What have I tried from here - this is attempt six ..

0) Changed permissions on Zones to be Dynamic updates from secure & nonsecure 
1) dcdiag /test:registerindns /dnsdomain:ejk.com /v
2) dcdiag /fix
3) net stop netlogon followed by a start of the service ...

I would add the pictures for all of this but am not allowed ...

To be clearer - without a workable DNS for this AD DS with the respective entries that should have been created by the new version of dcpromo.exe I cannot join any computers to the domain, I cannot resolve any addresses - even on the newly create domain controller no resolution of the domain name ejk.com is feasible ..

Nothing I do seems to work 
Any help/advice greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? I'm not understanding your question. Are you looking for a Reverse Lookup zone? They're not created by default and they aren't used by AD. If you want a Reverse Lookup zone you need to create it.

Comment: thanks for your comment - I've edited the text to be clearer ... the key problem is joining the domain ... if the prospective client machines cannot use this internal DNS to resolve the domain controller they can't join AD ...

Answer (score 1):

After 14 builds of this and going almost crazy I have finally cracked it. Such a simple thing. By default a new server of course registers the adapter with DNS. But specific to SoftLayer this tick box and the suffix tick box are "Unticked". So when building an AD service in SoftLayer you need to do this before adding the Roles & Features:

1. Go to Network and Sharing Center;
2. Click private network status;
3. Click properties;
4. Click IPV4;
5. Click properties;
6. Fill in preferred DNS server IP as your own IP;
7. Leave secondary empty;
8. Click advanced;
9. Choose the DNS tab;
10. Add your specific domain suffix;
11. Tick the boxes for "Register this connections address in DNS" & the "Use this connections DNS suffix"

And thats it ... as simple as that ... hope this saves someone else the time to figure it out. When you then install the Roles for AD & DNS the _msdcs entries should all be there. At worst you may have to manually (post the Roles install) do a net stop netlogon and then net start netlogon.

Cheers
EJK

Answer (score 0):

Is starting over an option? Usually you install only the AD DS role from server manager. You'll be prompted to install the DNS role later when you promote the server to the first DC. I suspect your problems came from running DNS before there was a domain. Since you already tried dcdiag /fix, your only other option continuing on would be to manually create each of the required entries and that can be a pain.

Comment: just tried it ... same result no _bsdcs entries created at all ... this must be a security error/issue ...